# map windows file system to unix style

Tags: windows, linux

On my dev box I have windows and the prod box is linux, one of the configuration file path points to c:\xxx\test.conf and /home/xxx/test.conf respectively.  
would it be possible to map c:\xxx to a unix style file path /home/xxx on windows
in other words, emulate unix style file system on windows

Comment: Which version of windows?  Can you clarify a little more?  Do you just want to be able to put the same path in the config file on windows and linux?

Comment: windows 7.   Yes I want to put the same path in the config file on windows and linux.  It's a java web application.  I know I can use ant build to set different paths when building, but I want to go further save that step too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cygwin, it performs such path mapping inside it.

Comment: but would application outside cygwin recognize the path mapping?

Comment: It would, if you start your application from within cygwin (e.g., using specially built jvm).